# System.IO.IOException : Invalid argument, when trying to save FormFile in web api

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

**UPDATE**:
It seems the issue is with Docker. When building the project using IIS Express everything works as expected. 
I will have to investigate why Docker is causing this issue.

I'm trying to save an image that is being sent to my API to local disk.

But I'm running into issues with the actual storing of the image.
I'm getting an `System.IO.IOException` when trying to save it.

Here's the API method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
     var filePath = @"C:\" + file.FileName + ".png";
     if(file.Length > 0)
     {
         using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
         {
             file.CopyTo(stream);
         }
     }
     return Ok();
 }
```

The file gets in fine and if I debug in Visual Studio I can see that it's the correct file that's being sent int. 
The code breaks on the `new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)` line.

I've tried with different paths like `C:\Pictures\` and `C:\users\myuser\pictures\` but nothing seems to work.

Exception details are:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Invalid argument'
Stack trace:
 >   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
 >   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
 >   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
 >   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
```

Comment: What exact error description you get? Maybe permission problem?

Comment: Don't you have opened a file with another program while you are trying to save changes to the file?

Comment: What's the exception message ? Please edit your question and add all the details about the error.

Comment: I've updated the post with the exception details.

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 what's the *actual* filename? Did you try debugging the code? The error complains that an argument to the FileStream constructor is invalid. In any case you should thank ASP.NET Core for not allowing you to write to `C:\ `. Can you imagine the damage a malformed POST request could do? What if the filename started with `Windows\System32\` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've updated the post. But the issue seemed to stem from Docker specifically and not the code itself. When building with IIS Express instead of Docker it works fine. I think there might be an issue with Docker and read/writing rights on the machine.

Comment: No, it's not working fine in IIS Express - in an actual IIS production environment you'd get a permission error. Application pool accounts *don't* have permission to write outside their folder. That code may run on a development machine when running under an administrator account. That doesn't mean it's working properly

Comment: As for Docker, what OS? `c:\whatever.png` isn't valid for Linux. And a Docker container will have even more restrictions than IIS. If you want to keep those files you'll have to store them in mapped storage locations. Anything else will be lost when the container shuts down

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes you are correct! I think that's the issue. I'm building docker for linux but it's currently running on Windows. How would you go about this? Have an external appsetting that checks if it's running on linux or windows and then selects an appropriate path depending on the OS?

Comment: There's no `C:\Pictures\ ` on Linux. You'll have to decide what you want to do in the first place - store images in a specific folder? You can put that folder in settings and combine it with the filename using `Path.Join()` or `Path.Combine()`. You could use `Path.GetFileName()` or `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` too, to get just the filename no matter what the POST request contains

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that you are getting the error when you run the app from inside a docker container. by default docker runs the container in Linux shell and Linux doesn't recognize the backslash in the path, instead you can use forward slash (/) in the path which works on both windows and Linux. The recommended way for combing the paths is to use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-3.1) instead of string concatenation. You can also check Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar and Path.DirectorySeparatorChar properties which can be used as well.

Please note also that c:\ does not exist on Linux , instead you should be specifying a relative path to your app or use a valid directory on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to use async version of `CopyTo` method -> `await file.CopyToAsync(stream)` just for the performance reasons.

It seems you can probably have opened this file in some editor and you receive the error:

> The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being
>   used by another process

If so, just close the editor where you have the file opened and everything should be working as expected.

**Another tip**: Instead of concatenating to get the path, try to use `Path.Combine` instead.

**EDIT after comments:**
As @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned in a comment:

> c:\whatever.png isn't valid for Linux. And a Docker container will
>   have even more restrictions than IIS. If you want to keep those files
>   you'll have to store them in mapped storage locations. Anything else
>   will be lost when the container shuts down